# How to replace group 1 of a regex with a given string in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

I have the following regex

```
regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(.*)|(.*)"
                                                  options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                    error:&error];
```

I want to replace the first group of a string matching this regex, with a value from a text field.

For example if I have `Hi|Peter` and replacing with `Goodbye` I get `Goodbye|Peter`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
NSString *s1 = @"Hi|Peter";
NSError *error;
NSString *pattern = @"(.*)\\|(.*)";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern
                                      options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                    error:&error];
NSString *s2 = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:s1
                           options:0
                         range:NSMakeRange(0, [s1 length])
                      withTemplate:@"Goodbye|$2"];
NSLog(@"%@", s2);
// Output: Goodbye|Peter
```

`$2` in the replacement template refers to the second capture group. Note that you have
to escape the "|" character in the regular expression.

Comment: I think this is it. Many thanks. I will try it out and come back to mark your answer as the right one.

Comment: I made a change to the template to fit in a value from a textfield `withTemplate:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$1|%@",textField.text]];`

Comment: @TiagoVeloso: So now you keep the first capture group and replace the second group?

Comment: I have two text fields, each edits a part of the regex. I guess I pasted the part where I edit the second group. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Sorry for taking this long. It worked by the way. Much appreciated.